# php html all dialog box opening

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dialog

My dialog box is in a for loop. 
Everytime I click the button all the dialog box for each button appears even if I click only one.

what can I do so only one dialog box appears?

Thank you!

Below is my code.

HTML CODE

```
<?php 
        foreach($people as $row){
        echo "<div class=dialog title='Basic dialog'>".$row->app_name."</div>";
       echo "<tr><td><button class='opener' name=name[]>".$row->app_name."</button></td></tr>";
                                    $x=$x+1;    
                                    }
                                ?>
```

My jquery from jqueryui.com

```
              $(function() {
                $( ".dialog" ).dialog({
                  autoOpen: false,
                  show: {
                    effect: "blind",
                    duration: 1000
                  },
                  hide: {
                    effect: "explode",
                    duration: 1000
                  }
                });

                $( ".opener" ).click(function() {
                  $( ".dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
                });
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$( ".opener" ).click(function() {
    $( ".dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
 });
```

try this

```
$( ".opener" ).click(function() {
    $(this).parents("tr:first").prev().dialog( "open" );
 });
```

Also you can use [closet()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) like below :

```
$( ".opener" ).click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.dialog').dialog( "open" );
     });
```

Comment: can you share your source code after creating a table on JSFiddle?

Comment: you could also use closest() for it

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of preference how to solve it. This is another one:

```
<?php
    $x = 1; // count from 1 
    foreach($people as $row){
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "<button class='opener' name=name[] data-target='#dialog-$x'>".$row->app_name."</button>";
        echo "<div class=dialog title='Basic dialog' id=dialog-$x>".$row->app_name."</div>";
        echo "</td></tr>";
        $x++; // will increase x with 1    
    }
?>
```

JS:

```
$(".opener").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $(target).dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: I copied it from your example and assumed it to be a counter. I will edit my code to show it's purpose.

Comment: so i will replace my whole javascript code with that small code?

Comment: No only the part with the click function.